# Why does Normal distort sound from SpeechSynthesize?

Tags: sound

I was reading the documentation on the [`SpeechSynthesize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SpeechSynthesize.html) function in Mathematica 11.2 and trying out the *Basic Examples*. They have `Normal` applied to the output of `SpeechSynthesize` (not sure for what purpose), and this appears to distort the sound to me. I.e., the following works normally:

```
SpeechSynthesize["Hello Wolfram"]
```

And the following, taken verbatim from the docs, results in growling with barely understandable words:

```
SpeechSynthesize["Hello Wolfram"] // Normal
```

The difference between `Normal` and un`Normal` versions of the output as it is presented in the Notebook UI is that the latter lets me click the `*.wav` file generated and open it in external program, while the former only has an icon with a waveform and no way to refer to the file.

I'm using 32-bit Mathematica 11.2 on a Linux 4.14 system.

So, what's happening here? Why do I get growling with `Normal`? And what was the reason to use `Normal` in the docs at all for the output?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue (OSX 10.14.6, WL 12), but: The `Normal` causes the audio to be read from memory rather than from a temporary file, explained in the `Audio` documentation as "Use Normal to bring the data in out-of-core audio objects into memory".  View the `InputForm` to see the difference. It would not shock me if the read-from-file version uses some substrate to play the file, and for in-memory audio, it does something else that is slightly less bulletproof.

Comment: @CarlLange actually yes, in the meantime I've played with it and seen that the `Normal` version contains the samples in a `List`, while the non-`Normal` one just has the filename. And the growling appears to not reproduce on 64-bit version, although doesn't play there either. Only the first 10% of the sound are played, which are also played normally on the 32-bit version before growling starts. On 64-bit MMA after the first 10% the playback simply stops. On MMA 11.3 and 12 (which are 64-bit-only) the issue doesn't happen at all.